# Umbraco - First run - connection string failed

Tags: installation, connection-string, umbraco

I just downloaded Umraco (via Web Platform Installer).

It takes me to this web page: 
[image]

How can I just select 'integrated security'?

That connection string is set to a blank database that exists. I have added 'IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool' and 'IIS APPPOOL\UmbracoTest' as database owner. The next screen is like this `Database configuration is invalid` for connection string `Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=UmbracoTest`:

[image]

That connection string is fine, I've used '.' datasource elsewhere with no problems (SQL Express).

Is there any way to get useful error messages?

How can I get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue during an Umbraco 6.1.5 installation. My issue was the providerName being empty as suggested, so when I added:

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I was able to install and upgrade my Umbraco 6.1.3 database. My full connection string is:

```
  <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="server=72.18.**.***,1533;database=mydatabase;user id=emma;password=******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is wrong, trust me :)

Instead of `DataSource=.` try `DataSource=.\sqlexpress`

Also ensure that the `initial catalog=UmbracoTest` is actually the correct name of the database.

Finally, since you are using an Umbraco 6.x version, the log files will be at `~App_Data/Logs` but in this case they will just tell you much the same as the install screen, that an `SqlException` has occurred.

**Edit:**

Looking at the Umbraco source, the error you see is raised by the following code:

```
if (_configured == false || 
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString) ||
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProviderName)))
{
    return new Result
                {
                    Message =
                        "Database configuration is invalid. Please check
                         that the entered database exists and that the provided 
                         username and password has write access to the
                         database.",
                    Success = false,
                    Percentage = "10"
                };
}
```

So my assumption is that you are missing the `Provider` from your connection string. In your web.config file your connection *should* look like this:

Comment: Thanks.

It isn't wrong :) - I have used '.' as a datasource in many other .net sites on my dev machine. I didn't name the sql server instance when I installed it. If you do that you can just use a '.' as datasource name.

When I open SQL Management Studio - I have '.' in the server name. I tried your way anyway - no change.

The DB name is also correct. Maybe there's a security issue but the error message is totally useless. I think this is a worrying sign so early in setup so I am trying Composite C1 instead - looks much better.

Comment: It seems a shame to stop using such a good tool like Umbraco because you can't get the connection string to work. I will add a couple more suggestions, and we'll get this sorted :)

Comment: Yes - well I was testing a few in parallel, and first impressions with Composite C1 are so good and keep getting better (my needs = super user friendly, simple, quick to setup). Have you used it? I spent weeks on Orchard which was way too complex. I think my decision is made. Will let you know if I come back :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I fixed it by adding the IIS_IUSRS user to the Umbraco site directory with "Modify" rights as the setup process is trying to write to the web.config with your connection string.  Hope this helps.